# Filter Information with cmd/batch script

Tags: batch-file, filter, cmd

I'm using "Disk Usage" (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651) to get the size of the recycle bin.

The problem is that I get a bunch of information that I don't need and I can't figure out how select the part that interests me.

The output of `du` command is:

> Files:        27
>
> Directories:  3
>
> Size:         322.675.258 bytes
>
> Size on disk: 322.773.120 bytes

I need a batch script or something that gives me only the Size value in a text file.

Comment: Do you have any scripting languages installed?  Or cygwin?  Or are you trying to do this with "native" windows commands?

Comment: At first I was trying to do it using only native commands, but I could also install third-party tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, set your desired folder before:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "folder=%systemdrive%\$RECYCLE.BIN"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('du "%folder%" 2^>nul') do (
set "size=!dsize!"
set "dsize=%%i")
>recycle.txt echo(%size%
```

Output is in `recycle.txt`.

Comment: Perfect!
Works like a charm! =D

Answer (score 0):

In a batch file, you use `for /f` to loop over lines of text.

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('du') do (
    if /i "%%a" equ "size" echo %%b
)
```

In your example, this should output:

```
322.675.258 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

If size in kilobytes is acceptable you could also do it like this:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=, tokens=6" %a in ('du -c') do echo %a >size.txt
```

Double the `%` signs for using this in a batch script.